# Java Bubble Sort ArrayList Exercise Issue

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

I have a java project that I am trying to use bubble sort to sort an `ArrayList` of books by rating.

I have three classes.

1. Books
2. Library
3. Sort

I'm having trouble getting the bubble sort to work, as everything I have tried either returns with an error, or random characters/numbers. If anyone could help my with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Books

```
public class Books {

    String title;
    int rating;

    public Video(String pTitle, int pRating) {
        title = pTitle;
        rating = pRating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}
```

Library

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Library {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Books>();

        Book book1 = new Book ("ThisBook 5", 5);
        Book book2 = new Book ("ThisBook 2", 2);
        Book book3 = new Book ("ThisBook 3", 3);
        Book book4 = new Book ("ThisBook 4", 4);
        Book book5 = new Book ("ThisBook 1", 1);

        bookList.add(book1);
        bookList.add(book2);
        bookList.add(book3);
        bookList.add(book4);
        bookList.add(book5);

        System.out.println("Original sequence");

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < bookList.size(); cnt++)
        {
            System.out.println(bookList.get(cnt).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(cnt).getRating());
        }

        System.out.println( "\r" + "Sorted By Rating");

        SortAlgorithm sortObject = new SortAlgorithm();
        sortObject.calc(bookList);

        System.out.println(bookList.get().getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get().getRating());
    }
}
```

I've been searching SO for different bubble sort algorithms but nothing seems to work. I think my problem has been with both the class names and bubble sort algorithm. I'm really banging my head here. If anyone can help me I'd really be grateful.

Comment: Where's your existing sort code that you've tried? What output/errors are you seeing? Need a little more info...

Comment: Also, what are you sorting on? Title? Rating? Both? Bubble sort works by iteratively going through each item in the list and moving it to the proper location from the end of the list, repeating until all items are sorted. Hence "bubbling" each item to its sorted location.

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to get a sort on the rating. Ascending or descending. If I can get something to work I think it will be easier to alter for the opposite from there.

Comment: I'm still a bit of a Java noob, but on the naming things front, if I'm not mistaken, classes are supposed to be nouns, whilst methods are to be verbs. I haven't really got time to look  at this as I'm in a rush, but perhaps to  fit in with this, you could make 'sort' a method in your Library class.

Answer (score 0):

This is just complicated code for no reason..

```
public class Sort {
public static void calc(ArrayList<Book> bookList) {
    for (i = 0 ; i < bookList.size() ; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < bookList.size() ; j++) {
            if (bookList.get(i).getRating() > bookList.get(j).getRating()) {
                Collections.swap(bookList, i, j);
            }
            System.out.println(bookList.get(out).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(out).getRating());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: The println isn't doing anything for me. Even when I replace (out) with (i) or (j) it just prints duplicate books in odd order.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here:

1. You seem to have changed the `Books` class from `Video` to `Books` at some point but you didn't update it everywhere. Notice the old `Video` constructor. I see mixed references to `bookList` and `videoList` in the `Library` and `Sort` classes as well.
2. In the last line of `Library.main()` you use `videoList.get()` without a parameter, which is invalid.
3. You try to create a  `new SortAlgorithm()` but the class is named `Sort`

As far as the algorithm goes:

You are using `get()` and `add()` but you are never removing from the bookList. You'll end up with more items in the final list than you started with. Instead of `get()` you may want to use `remove()`.

Also, I'd avoid complicating your for loops and stick with standard `int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++` setup.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bookList.size() - 1; j++) {

        // get the books you want to compare (remove them from the list)

        // insert them back into the list in the correct order
    }
}
```

You're not too far off from the solution, and seeing as how this appears to be homework hopefully that's enough to get you there.

Comment: Yes, I have been copy/pasting a bit from another project. I had started over a few times. I have them fixed in my project now. I'm just having problems with the bubble sort.

Comment: Also watch out for your `println()` in the `Sort.calc()` method, it'll make it look like your sort isn't working if you leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

Book class:

```
package bubbleSorter;

public class Book {

    String title;
    int rating;

    public Book(String pTitle, int pRating) {
        title = pTitle;
        rating = pRating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

}
```

Library class:

```
package bubbleSorter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        Book book1 = new Book ("ThisBook 5", 5);
        Book book2 = new Book ("ThisBook 2", 2);
        Book book3 = new Book ("ThisBook 3", 3);
        Book book4 = new Book ("ThisBook 4", 4);
        Book book5 = new Book ("ThisBook 1", 1);

        bookList.add(book1);
        bookList.add(book2);
        bookList.add(book3);
        bookList.add(book4);
        bookList.add(book5);

        System.out.println("Original sequence");
        System.out.println();

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < bookList.size(); cnt++)
        {
            System.out.println(bookList.get(cnt).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(cnt).getRating());
        }

        System.out.println( "\r" + "Sorted By Rating");
        System.out.println();

        LibraryHandler libraryHandler = new LibraryHandler();
        libraryHandler.bubbleSort(bookList);

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < bookList.size(); cnt++)
        {
            System.out.println(bookList.get(cnt).getTitle() + "   " + bookList.get(cnt).getRating());
        }

    }

}
```

LibraryHandler class:

```
package bubbleSorter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LibraryHandler {

    public void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Book> bookList) {

        Book temp = new Book("ThisBook 0", 0);
        int n = bookList.size();

        for (int i =0;i<n;i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n-i; j++) {
                if (bookList.get(j-1).getRating() > bookList.get(j).getRating()) {
                    // swap them
                    temp = bookList.get(j-1);
                    bookList.set(j-1, bookList.get(j));
                    bookList.set(j, temp);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

That was great fun!

It might be possible to improve the names of the classes here.  Library is the main class, so you might just want to call it Main.  As I said in my comment, I think the convention is to use nouns for class names and verbs for method names, so I'd advise you to stick to that.

To get the bubbleSort algorithm working I just googled it and literally copied someone's implementation, changing only the bits that had to be changed: theirs was for sorting an array of ints.

Here's a link to the page with that implementation on:

http://www.java-examples.com/java-bubble-sort-example

Don't worry about all the warnings that may or may not appear at the top of that page: the code below this is what I adapted and it worked fine.